# Laravel - Special Characters doesn't work in controller

Tags: php, laravel, character-encoding, encode

When I try to `echo` or `var_dump` a variable with special characters doesn't work.

It save the values correctly in database. It show correctly at view but in controller no.

For example:

```
echo 'Março';

returns MarÃ§o
```

I already have problems when I try to do a select.

How can I solve that.

Comment: Properly the character encoding going wrong somewhere, I'd check if both of your files have the same encoding / if you're changing encoding during the process.

Comment: your php file encode in UTF-8 ?

Comment: My php file is UTF-8 @kenken9999

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

just make sure that the above declaration is there in your head definition of the HTML.
that should work it out :)

Comment: Yes. I have this in my head @NawafAlharby